# Why is this setting for Name-based Virtual Host settings not working?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two domains (siteA.com & SiteB.com) that point to the same webserver and I would like to show different web pages for each.

The steps I have taken so far are:

Copy the default site (siteA) to siteB

1) `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/siteB` 
2) `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/siteB`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@siteB.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/siteB
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/siteB>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost *:80>
```

Then I created under /var/www/siteB and created a sample index.html in there.

However when I load my domain `siteB.com` I still get directed to `/var/www/siteA`. Why is that?

Do I have to rename the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/siteA` as well?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the answer below it seems I had forgotten next to enabling the site also another entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin info@siteB.com
            ServerName siteB.com
            ServerAlias www.siteB.com
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

in order to include all subdomains as well then do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerAdmin info@siteB.com
            ServerName siteB.com
            ServerAlias *.siteB.com
</VirtualHost *:80>
```

Same goes for siteA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable siteB by using command **a2ensite siteB** and then restart the webserver?

Comment: Oh right. I missed that thank alot.  I also added to each site ServerName siteA.com ServerAlias www.siteA.com and same for siteb. Is that mandatory to do?

Comment: I prefer to go for *.siteA.com which means all subdomains of siteA.com.

Comment: I see, its a bit hard to follow this up in comments. I have updated the question. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes, "ServerAlias *.siteB.com" is exactly how I like it to be :)

Comment: You should vote my answer not my comment :P

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for days with a virtualhost problem... Maybe related:
Here is what I had:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName www.domain1.com
     ServerAlias domain1.com
     Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/domain1.include

     <IfModule mpm_peruser_module>
            ServerEnvironment apache apache
     </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost domain2:80>
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    Include /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/domain2.include

    <IfModule mpm_peruser_module>
            ServerEnvironment apache apache
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

domain1 was sending out domain2s content!

Finally I changed

```
<VirtualHost domain2:80>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

and it worked.

- "IP" based virtualhost setting was running on domain2, which has the same IP as domain1, and was never even looking at my first VirtualHost entry
- The tags need to be identical IP [and port] for it to look at ServerName and ServerAlias

Hope this helps someone.